# How to return a cursor from an anonymous block from a DB2 z/OS database in .NET

Tags: c#, sql, cursor, db2, zos

According to the examples in the IBM documentation ([see this page](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.swg.im.dbclient.adonet.doc/doc/t0011822.html?cp=SSEPEK_10.0.0/7-2-1-3-1-5&lang=en)) it should be possible in .NET to return a DB2 z/OS cursor from an anonymous block and loop over the results with a datareader, however the following code crashes with the following exception:

**ERROR [42601] [IBM][DB2] SQL0104N  An unexpected token "CURSOR1" was found following "".  Expected tokens may include:  "SECTION"."**

Test code:

```
[Test]
public void Test()
{
    using (var conn = new DB2Connection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnection"].ConnectionString))
    {
        conn.Open();
        using (var cmd = new DB2Command("BEGIN " +
                                        "DECLARE CURSOR1 CURSOR WITH RETURN TO CLIENT WITH HOLD FOR SELECT ID, DESCRIPTION FROM ITEMS; "+
                                        "OPEN CURSOR1; "+
                                        "END;", conn))
        {
            using (var rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (rdr.Read())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", rdr.GetString(0), rdr.GetString(1));
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

My database is a DB2 V10 database running on z/OS.
I'm using DB2 Connect V10.5.3...

Has anyone got this to work?

Comment: You are referencing the manual for DB2 10.5 for LUW, not DB2 10 for z/OS. As far as I know, the latter does not support anonymous blocks.

Comment: I specifically filtered for DB2 V10 on z/OS.  If you check the page I refer to you can see the filter on top AND in the top of the table of contents...